# How to retrieve text inside label tag through lxml?

Tags: parsing, web-scraping, lxml, lxml.html

I am using lxml to fetch text inside tags, and doing in this way

```
  xpaths_for_questions_lxml = []
    for tag in self.tree.iter():
        try:
            if tag.text and utils.is_question(tag.text.strip()):
                xpaths_for_questions_lxml.append(self.tree.getpath(tag))

        except Exception as e:
            self.logger.debug(traceback.format_exc())
            raise Exception
```

> is_question module returns true if the statement has question mark

But when tag type is **label** the tag.text attribute is empty, it is not showing any text even though there is text inside the label tag in the actual [webpage](https://www.amctheatres.com/faqs/movie-info).

Why label tag is not showing any text content? or anything additional needed to be done to fetch through label tags?

**EDIT1: My question is, i am iterating through all children in dom tree, but why text inside label is not showing up?**

Comment: Which element exactly you need to handle?

Comment: any question in the page

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get questions you can try

```
r = requests.get('https://www.amctheatres.com/faqs/movie-info')
source = html.fromstring(r.text)
questions = source.xpath('//label[@itemprop="text"]/text()')
```

or

```
questions = [label.text_content() for label in source.xpath('//label[@itemprop="text"]')]
```

Note that `label.text_content()` should be used instead of `label.text` because `label` nodes contain more than one child text nodes

```
print(questions)
#['Does the runtime shown for each movie include trailers?', 'Where can I find MPAA movie ratings information?', 'What does advertised showtime mean?', 'What movies are playing right now at AMC?', 'What movies are coming soon to AMC?', 'How can I find movie times at AMC?']
```

Comment: why it is failing with the code i attached, ideally it should work for any tag right?

Comment: Do you mean that you're getting `is_question module returns true if the statement has question mark` with my code?

Comment: No, with using label in selector expression it works, but when i am iterating over whole dom, why label is not showing any text in it

Comment: Oh... You mean your code? I didn't try it as it seemed to be overcomplicated for this task. The problem might be in additional condition `utils.is_question(tag.text.strip())`  which I don't know what exactly suppose to do

Comment: No, just treat it as a module , which takes input as a string and returns true if the string has question mark at end

Comment: @Satyaaditya Why not just to use `tag.text.strip().endswith('?')` ?

Comment: similar thing is happening in that module, but question is, i am iterating through the all elements in tree but why i am unable to find the text inside label tag?

Comment: @Satyaaditya , that's because in `lxml` `text` property returns *first text child node*, but not *complete string representation*. If you want to get text content of label you should use `text_content` method. For instance `[i.text for i in tree.xpath('//label')]` returns `[None, None, None, None, None, None]` (I expected to get list of empty strings, but for some reason `lxml` behaves like that) while `[i.text_content() for i in tree.xpath('//label')]` returns the list of questions

Comment: yeah, thank you. can you please edit answer with this,  so that it may help someone else, and also for me to accept :)